# Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70 symbol trademark converted to question mark

Tags: jdbc, unicode, informix

1. IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70 on rhel 2.6
2. some info

   ```
   select distinct dbs_collate 
   from sysmaster:sysdbslocale;

   dbs_collate
   -----------

   en_US.819
   ```
3. my jdbc

   ```
   jdbc.ep.ifx.url=jdbc:informix-sqli://server:9999/testdb:informixserver=test_shm;IFX_USE_STRENC=true;
   ```
4. the table

   ```
   create table test
   (
   id serial,
   notes nchar(5120)
   );
   ```
5. what am i trying to achieve

   - use a web-base app to add text to an Informix table thru JDBC
   - text can be anything including symbols (eg copyright, trademark)
6. what currently works

   - i can add whatever text,symbols into the table,
   - but certain symbol eg trademark will be saved as "?".
7. my question

   - how do i make the symbol saved and displayed properly instead of being converted to "?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some characters are not represented in `en_US.819`. You can see how it looks at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 There is `copyright` and `reserved` characters while I cannot see `trade mark`.

I have made simple Jython program that inserts such characters into Informix database. My test database uses Polish encoding `pl_PL.1250`.

```
insert into test_nchar (id, notes) values (1, 'copyright: ©')
insert into test_nchar (id, notes) values (2, 'registered: ®')
insert into test_nchar (id, notes) values (3, 'trademark: ™')
Something is terrible wrong with [insert into test_nchar (id, notes) values (3, 'trademark: ™')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jdbc_ifx_encoding.py", line 20, in run_sql
    c.execute(sql)
SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: B\u0142\u0105d konwersji kod\xf3w wskutek zabronionej sekwencji lub b\u0142\u0119dnej warto\u015bci.
SELECT ...
1: [copyright: Â©]
2: [registered: Â®]
```

I try to translate error message from Polish to English: `Error while code conversion because of disallowed sequence or wrong value.` This message if for `INSERT` with trademark character. Trademark is not available nor for Polish CP1250 I use, nor for CP819 you use. Maybe you inserted it using other technology like ODBC?

You can also see that select shows strange characters before copyright/registered character.

I think that the only solution is to create new database with Unicode encoding like UTF-8.